How can I monitor movement of subterranean wall?
I'd like to utilize smart sensor(s) to monitor any gradual movement of my garage/basement wall. The wall is partially under ground and the cracking you see in the picture occurred before the reinforcement was added. I'm unsure what direction to go in trying to keep track of this wall using smart sensors.

What type of sensor(s) will help me keep track of movement? Will door/window sensors recognize small changes in angle enough to trigger an event?
I prefer Z-Wave devices and have a SmartThings Hub to connect both Zigbee and Z-Wave.
I would prefer not to change the battery more than a few times a year.



an accelerometer measures acceleration ... if an object moves at a constant speed,  then there is no acceleration ... the wall's acceleration is too small to measure anyway ... measure distance instead ... a question about sensors is not a question about IoT ... when you have chosen a sensor and have problems with transmitting the data to a remote location, then the question would be about IoT

@jsotola Correct, but most smart sensors with accelerometers like door/window sensors can report angle (tilt) as well. I'm just not sure what the resolution/accuracy of those values are and if it is enough to rely on for this use-case.
The question is relevant to IoT because I'm unaware of what is the appropriate type of IoT device. e.g. Door/Window sensor, Laser, Infrared, etc.

find a suitable sensor first ... worry about remote monitoring after

You didn’t add the picture you refer to (may be useful to understand the directions and amplitudes we are talking about), but I do indeed think that the amplitudes are probably too small for common off the shelf hardware with instantaneous measurements (otherwise you probably would have had to tear down the house already). You probably need to have (very) precise measurements over long periods. And the more accurate the more expensive, usually. Not sure if distance (with laser ToF readings) or angle would be most useful or practical, though.

Movement relative to what?? When you answer that question ... then I would attach a sensor between that object and the wall. What type? Well, industry & construction sensors are plenty.  But are not cheap. @ me and I'll make a more complete answer. But I think the cost will keep you looking for alternatives.

@st2000 I'm sorry, I forgot to add the image when I posted. I was assuming that a two part sensor (like magnetic switches) could be placed above and below the lateral crack. Therefore if the "contact" breaks I can get an alert through my existing smart home system. It would be great if I could rely on common smart home sensors to track this, but considering the alternative repair costs it may be worth going industrial.

Ah! It's a cinder block wall. All those block could move independently! What a mes...  challenge. I saw some industrial strange gauges bolted across a building foundation crack. But a block wall... ??? Maybe something on this web page might work.

a ruler and a webcam might work ... acquire an image once a day
